# JqGrid Virtual Scrolling causes div's inside bdiv  have wrong height

Tags: jqgrid

The DOM Looks like this:

```html
<div class="ui-jqgrid-dbiv" style="width:998px; height:200px">
    <div style="height:1151702px; position:relative">
        <div style="height:680800px;">
```

It looks like the jqGrid API is causing it. We have scroll set to true which is virtual paging turned on. In some case a few rows in the grid are populated and on DOM inspection we are seeing these side effects. Does anyone one with JQGrid experience explain what is going on and how to fix this problem!

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#ContentPanel1__01TestCustomerList').jqGrid(
           {
              datatype:function(postdata) {            
                $('#ContentPanel1__01TestCustomerList').listContentPart('getData', postdata); },
             page: 1,
             colNames: ["A/C Ref","Name","Short Name","Credit Limit"],colModel: [{"classes":"sage200-gridCell","name":"CustomerAccountNumber","index":"CustomerAccountNumber","formatter":DefaultFormat,"unformat":unformatField,"searchoptions":{"attr":{"title":"contains"},"sopt":["eq","ne","cn","nc","bw","bn"]}},{"classes":"sage200-gridCell","name":"CustomerAccountName","index":"CustomerAccountName","formatter":DefaultFormat,"unformat":unformatField,"searchoptions":{"attr":{"title":"contains"},"sopt":["eq","ne","cn","nc","bw","bn"]}},{"classes":"sage200-gridCell","name":"CustomerAccountShortName","index":"CustomerAccountShortName","formatter":DefaultFormat,"unformat":unformatField,"searchoptions":{"attr":{"title":"contains"},"sopt":["eq","ne","cn","nc","bw","bn"]}},{"classes":"sage200-gridCell","name":"CreditLimit","index":"CreditLimit","formatter":CurrencyFormat,"unformat":unformatField,"searchoptions":{"attr":{"title":"equals"},"sopt":["eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge"]}}],
viewrecords: true,
scrollrows: false,
prmNames: { id: "CustomerAccountNumber" },
shrinkToFit: false,
pager: jQuery('#ContentPanel1__01TestCustomerList_pager'),
onSelectRow: function (a,b) { OnRowSelect('ContentPanel1__01TestCustomerList', a, b); },
ondblClickRow: function (event){ GridDoubleClick(event.target); },
loadError: jqGrid_aspnet_loadErrorHandler,gridComplete: function () { $("#ContentPanel1__01TestCustomerList").listContentPart("onInit"); },
resizeStop: function(newWidth, index) { $("#ContentPanel1__01TestCustomerList").listContentPart("onColumnResize", newWidth, index); },
hoverrows: false,
scroll: 1,
rowNum: 25,
rowList: [10,20,30],
editDialogOptions: {"recreateForm":true,errorTextFormat:function(data) { return 'Error: ' + data.responseText },editData:{ __RequestVerificationToken: jQuery('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() }},addDialogOptions: {"recreateForm":true,errorTextFormat:function(data) { return 'Error: ' + data.responseText },editData:{ __RequestVerificationToken: jQuery('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() }},delDialogOptions: {"recreateForm":true,errorTextFormat:function(data) { return 'Error: ' + data.responseText },delData:{ __RequestVerificationToken: jQuery('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() }},searchDialogOptions: {onReset:ContentPanel1_onReset,"multipleSearch":true,"sFilter":"ObeyOperatorFilters",onInitializeSearch:ContentPanel1_onInitializeSearch,afterRedraw:ContentPanel1_afterRedraw,"modal":true,"Find":"Apply",onSearch:ContentPanel1_onSearch,"width":600,beforeShowSearch:ContentPanel1_beforeShowSearch,"recreateForm":true,"caption":"Advanced Filter"},jsonReader: {id:"id",page:function (obj) { return obj.page; },root:function (obj) {return obj.$resources;},records:function (obj) { return obj.$totalResults;},total:function (obj) { return obj.total; },repeatitems:false},sortorder: 'asc',multiselect: true,width: '250',height: '200',viewsortcols: [false,'vertical',true]})
    .navGrid('#ContentPanel1__01TestCustomerList_pager',{"edit":false,"add":false,"del":false,"search":true,"refresh":true,"view":false,"position":"left","cloneToTop":true},jQuery('#ContentPanel1__01TestCustomerList').getGridParam('editDialogOptions'),jQuery('#ContentPanel1__01TestCustomerList').getGridParam('addDialogOptions'),jQuery('#ContentPanel1__01TestCustomerList').getGridParam('delDialogOptions'),jQuery('#ContentPanel1__01TestCustomerList').getGridParam('searchDialogOptions') );
    function jqGrid_aspnet_loadErrorHandler(xht, st, handler) {jQuery(document.body).css('font-size','100%'); jQuery(document.body).html(xht.responseText);};});
```

Comment: Have you set `overflow-y` to `scroll`  or `auto`? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Could you post the grid (the demo) which can be used to reproduces the program?

Comment: @Oleg I have posted the jqgrid code

Comment: @chugh97: Sorry, but I am now in another country at one customer and can't answer your question. One thing which I see is the usage on `datatype` as function. I don't think that you can combine it with virtual scrolling. I recommend always never ever to use `datatype` as function and as soon as possible not use virtual scrolling. In your case you chosen the worst two features which I know in good product jqGrid and try to use there together...